# Interpreting the angle from the angle obtained by atan2 function

Tags: matlab

I have two signals ($x$ and $y$) whose absolute phases I'm calculating by using the `atan2` function. Then subtracting both I'm getting the relative phase between two signals.

Because the absolute phase is calculated by `atan2`, its range is $[-\pi,\pi]$. Now the relative phase I got after subtracting the absolute phase, how do I convert this to $[0,2\pi]$?

My efforts: On the final relative phase obtained by `atan2`. I'm doing this

```
if phase >= 0 then
phase = 360 - phase;
else
phase = abs(phase);
end
```

This is yielding good results and matches with the phase between the signals $x$ and $y$, except in the ranges $[0,10]$ and $[350,360]$.

Other methods:

```
Method1 = abs(rad2deg(mod(phase1,2*pi) - mod(phase2,2*pi)))
%%%% 2nd Method %%%%%
Angles360 = @(a) rem(360+a, 360);
X_2pi = Angles360(rad2deg(X));
Y_2pi = Angles360(rad2deg(Y));
Method2 = abs(X_2pi - Y_2pi);
```

But all three methods have the same problem, if I'm giving initial phase difference as $1$ and run the simulation for $1000$ trials, I'm getting o/p as $357,359,1,5,8,\ldots$. Why is it getting wrapped to $357,359$?